# ng-grid groupBy pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ng-grid

I am using angularjs ng-grid and I am facing problem with the pagination when grouping the records by any column. The pagination depends on the number of child rows. But my requirement is that the pagination should be based on the number of grouped rows.